# Error: haml syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, haml

Have converted devise new session from erb to Haml but doens't work, this is the code:

```
%div.row.show-grid
 %div.span8.offset7
  %h1 Sign in

  - form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| 
   %div.clearfix
   = f.label :email 
    %div.input
     = f.email_field :email, :class => 'xlarge', :id => 'admin_email' 
    %div.clearfix       
    = f.label :password 
    %div.input
     = f.password_field :password, :class => 'xlarge', :id => 'admin_password' 
     - if devise_mapping.rememberable? 
      %div = f.check_box :remember_me  
      = f.label :remember_me 
    %div = f.submit "Sign up"
```

and this is the originally erb code:

```
<div class="row show-grid">
    <div class="span8 offset7">


<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Sign in</h1>
  </div>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <div class="clearfix">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <div class="input">
              <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'xlarge', :id => 'admin_email' %>
            </div>
          </div>

   <div class="clearfix">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <div class="input">
              <%= f.password_field :password, :class => 'xlarge', :id => 'admin_password' %>
            </div>
          </div>
            <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

          <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you can use `.class` and `#id` directly, they're a shortcut for `%div.class` and `%div#id`

Second, this error is usually triggered in a "block" of code, as in:

```
- if cond
  =# instr
```

or

```
- form_for(options) do |f|
  =# instr
```

Giving us the error line would help. But I'd say you messed up with indentation in one of said code blocks.

**EDIT**

Oh I get it. You forgot to indent line 7, `= f.label :email`. Also, `%tag = code` won't work, you have to either nest it, or do it with `%tag= code`

Comment: error is on line 21(the text of line is indicated as 0), but the page has 17 lines of code whitout any line space, or empty new lines

Comment: @Angelbit may be the problem with your `application.html.haml` file?

Comment: @Katen Thanks, now works, but this problem is inside line 8 "%div.input" line 7 is indented.

Comment: Yep, the source of the error was that you were nesting content under a `f.label`. But having worked with bootstrap recently, I'm assuming you want you `f.label` and your `.input` within your `.clearfix`, and your `f.text_field` within your `.input`